# Saving file from NSString. Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, file, nsstring

How can i do this? 
I know ho to do this on windows, but here.. im newer ))

SDK: Mac OS X 10.5

Comment: How to use save dialogs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the answer in the [NSString reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) with the `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method.